# Diophantine equation considering primes

Tags: number-theory

I want to find the prime solutions for the equation $2^p=q^q+q+2$.

So far I came up with solutions $(p,q)=(3,2),(5,3)$. I don't think there are any other solutions, but I'm struggling to prove this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $q\geq 3$. Then $p$ is odd and we have:
$$ 2\underbrace{(2^{p-1}-1)}_a = q(q^{q-1}+1)$$
Since $3|a$ we have $3|q(q^{q-1}+1)$. If $3|q^{q-1}+1=z^2+1^2$ we
get $3|1$. So $3|q$ and thus $q=3$.

Answer (score 0):

We have :
$$2^n -2 ≡ 0 mod n, n prime$$

$$q(q^{q-1} +1)≡ 0 mod n$$
Except for primes n=3 and n=5 which give q=2 and q=3 respectively, for other primes $$q^q +q>> 2^n -2$$.
Therefore your solutions are the only possible solutions.